# How to make an activity background transparent and blur the background

Tags: android, android-activity, android-blur-effect, android-renderscript

When I launch my app, it launches an `Activity` which should have transparent header and whatever is the currently shown in background should be blurred.

[image]

I am able to get the transparency. But I am not able to figure out how to blur the background. For example if I launch app from home screen, then home screen should be visible but blurred out.

I have an idea to use Framebuffer to get current displayed data, but how to convert that to bitmap which I can use to draw an image without saving the image and directly using data.

I also know that We can take screenshot by *pressing power and volume button*. Does anyone has an idea where is the code in android to do that? My app will have system access.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> how to blur the background?

You can use `RenderScript` available in support library

```
public class BlurBuilder {
    private static final float BITMAP_SCALE = 0.4f;
    private static final float BLUR_RADIUS = 7.5f;

    public static Bitmap blur(Context context, Bitmap image) {
        int width = Math.round(image.getWidth() * BITMAP_SCALE);
        int height = Math.round(image.getHeight() * BITMAP_SCALE);

        Bitmap inputBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(image, width, height, false);
        Bitmap outputBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(inputBitmap);

        RenderScript rs = RenderScript.create(context);
        ScriptIntrinsicBlur theIntrinsic = ScriptIntrinsicBlur.create(rs, Element.U8_4(rs));
        Allocation tmpIn = Allocation.createFromBitmap(rs, inputBitmap);
        Allocation tmpOut = Allocation.createFromBitmap(rs, outputBitmap);
        theIntrinsic.setRadius(BLUR_RADIUS);
        theIntrinsic.setInput(tmpIn);
        theIntrinsic.forEach(tmpOut);
        tmpOut.copyTo(outputBitmap);

        return outputBitmap;
    }
}
```

see [this link](https://futurestud.io/blog/how-to-blur-images-efficiently-with-androids-renderscript/) for more details

Or you can use [Blurry](https://github.com/wasabeef/Blurry)

> Does anyone has an idea where is the code in android to do that?

For taking screenshot of your app screen see [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2661536/how-to-programatically-take-a-screenshot-on-android)

Comment: It takes bitmap as an input. My problem is that whatever is behind my activity, e.g, home screen, should get blurred, I tried getting bitmap from my activity root view but that simply return me my view's background (which i set to a transparent with an image) and not home screen. I want something like WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_BLUR_BEHIND which would have blurred anything in background. How can i do this?

Answer (score 4):

I used this to give a blur effect to my edit text background, you can modify it according to your preference, play around with opacity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><!--  res/drawable/rounded_edittext.xml -->
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <gradient
        android:centerColor="#33FFFFFF"
        android:endColor="#33FFFFFF"
        android:gradientRadius="270"
        android:startColor="#33FFFFFF"
        android:type="radial" />
    <corners
        android:bottomLeftRadius="25dp"
        android:bottomRightRadius="25dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="25dp"
        android:topRightRadius="25dp" />
</shape>
```

alternatively, you might be interested in [this](https://github.com/500px/500px-android-blur)  or [this](https://github.com/faradaj/BlurBehind)

As one more alternative you can use a small blur bitmap and repeat it:

```
    <xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/MainLayout"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/backrepeat"
    >
```

Then prepare:

```
    <bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:src="@drawable/back" 
        android:tileMode="repeat" />
```

Comment: That <shape> does not blur anything.